# Product of terms involving eigenvalues and an eigenvector.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

Let $A_{n\times n}$ be a matrix and $\lambda_1,\lambda_2\ldots \lambda_k$ be $k$ eigenvalues of $A$. Let $x$ be an eigenvector of $A$ corresponding to eigenvalue $\lambda_3$. Then without expanding prove that $(A-\lambda_1 I)(A-\lambda_2 I)\cdots (A-\lambda_k I)x=0.$

Please help me to prove this.

Comment: You could try by induction over $k$, starting with $k=3$.

Comment: How the induction will work here as to how do we go for $k=2$

Comment: If $k=2$, your problem makes no sense since $\lambda_3$ does not exist. So you prove it for $k=3$, and then show for $k\geq 3$ with an induction step-

Comment: Does $(A-\alpha I)$ commute with $(A-\beta I)$?  That is, does $(A-\alpha I)(A-\beta I) = (A-\beta I)(A-\alpha I)$?  Use this result then to show that $(A-\lambda_1 I)(A-\lambda_2 I)(A-\lambda_3 I)\cdots (A-\lambda_k I)x$ $= (A-\lambda_1 I)(A-\lambda_2 I)(A-\lambda_4 I)\cdots (A-\lambda_k I)(A-\lambda_3 I)x$, having moved the special term in the product we care about to the end so it can act on $x$ first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume $n\ge 3$ so that eigenvalue $\lambda_3$ exists.

$(A-\lambda_3 I)x = 0$ by definition of eigenvalue and eigenvector.

$A$ and $I$ commute, so we can rearrange the terms.

$$\left[\prod_{j\ne 3}(A-\lambda_j I)\right](A-\lambda_3 I) x = 0.$$

Okay, after posting this, looked at the comments.  @JMoravitz already gave the answer there!